# Socket.io connect event never fired

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm using nodejs and socket.io to create a socket server. Problem is, on the client and server, the connect event is never fired. My code for the client is this:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8002");

console.log(socket); // This works

socket.on('connect', function(){
   console.log('connected');  // Does not show meaning event not fired
});
```

Then, on the server this is what I got:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer().listen(8002);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var cookie_reader = require('cookie');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var redis = require('redis');

//Configure socket.io to store cookie set by Django
io.use(function(){
    io.set('authorization', function(data, accept){
        if(data.headers.cookie){
            data.cookie = cookie_reader.parse(data.headers.cookie);
            return accept(null, true);
        }
        return accept('error', false);
    });
    // io.set('log level', 1);
    // io.set('origins', 'http://127.0.0.1:8001');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("Someone connected"); // Nothing shows
    // Create redis client
    /*client = redis.createClient();

    // Subscribe to the Redis events channel
    client.subscribe('notifications.' + socket.handshake.cookie['sessionid']);

    // Grab message from Redis and send to client
    client.on('message', function(channel, message){
        console.log('on message', message);
        socket.send(message);
    });

    // Unsubscribe after a disconnect event
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        client.unsubscribe('notifications.' + socket.handshake.cookie['sessionid']);
    });*/
});
```

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.machinalis.com/blog/rt-django-notifications/), if it helps. What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Unless you need redis / django and all that other fancy stuff,

I suggest just using the Get Started doc on socket.io's website:

http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: I really need those but I've been able to narrow down the issue to nodejs code on the io.use() section i.e. Configure socket.io to store cookie set by Django